# If-statement won't check NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I am trying to create an if statement that checks to see if the selected cell is equal to an object in an array and if it is then it will set an NSURL accordingly. The table that I am referencing is from another view controller called PopOverViewController that I have created a delegate and used in the destinationViewController.

ViewController.m:

```
-(void) didLoadSelectedLayer:(NSString *)selectedLayer{
self.popOverArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Electric Radio", @"Electric Truck", @"Gas Radio", @"Gas Truck", @"Meter", @"Sewer Radio", @"Sewer Truck", @"Support Radio", @"Support Truck", @"Water Radio", @"Water Truck", @"Select All", nil];

if ([_popoverTableVC.myTable.indexPathForSelectedRow isEqual:@"Electric Radio"]) {
    _url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somewebsite.com"];
}else{

}
```

I originally had a switch statement but since switch statements cannot use NSStrings I am confused on how to achieve the desired effect.

This is the PopOverViewController.h where I create the delegate:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <ArcGIS/ArcGIS.h>

#pragma mark - popoverTableViewControllerDelegate

@protocol popOverTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void) didLoadSelectedLayer:(NSString *)selectedLayer;


@end

@interface PopOverTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
AGSFeatureLayer *popOverLayer;

IBOutlet UITableView *myTable;


}
@property (nonatomic, strong)IBOutlet UITableView *myTable;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *popOverArray;
@property (nonatomic,strong) id<popOverTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
//-(void)didSelectObject:(UITableView *)tableView :(NSInteger *)key;
@end
```

This is the PopOverViewController.m:

```
#import "PopOverTableViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

#pragma mark - PopOverTableViewControler

@interface PopOverTableViewController ()
{
    NSURL *_url;
    ViewController *_ViewController;
}

@end

@implementation PopOverTableViewController
@synthesize delegate;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.popOverArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Electric Radio", @"Electric Truck", @"Gas Radio", @"Gas Truck", @"Meter", @"Sewer Radio", @"Sewer Truck", @"Support Radio", @"Support Truck", @"Water Radio", @"Water Truck", @"Select All", nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.popOverArray count];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        NSString *selectedLayer = [_popOverArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
        [self.delegate didLoadSelectedLayer:selectedLayer];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.popOverArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


@end
```

Comment: Lyndsey's & Ryan's answers below provide a solution to your problem, but according to your logic `- tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` should be `- tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` (`select` vs `deselect`)

Comment: Also... since you're passing the string corresponding to the selection (`selectedLayer`), why don't you just compare that instead?

Comment: I used `if ([selectedLayer isEqualToString:@"Electric Radio"])` and it worked for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional is incorrectly checking the `NSIndexPath` of the selected row against your `NSString`:

```
if ([_popoverTableVC.myTable.indexPathForSelectedRow isEqual:@"Electric Radio"]) {
```

You should instead compare your string to the contents of the array's index which corresponds to your selected row:

```
if ([[self.popOverArray objectAtIndex:_popoverTableVC.myTable.indexPathForSelectedRow.row] isEqual:@"Electric Radio"]) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[_popoverTableVC.myTable.indexPathForSelectedRow isEqual:@"Electric Radio"]
```

This line of code is comparing a `NSIndexPath` with a `NSString`. It will never be true. You'll have to get the string of that row for this to work. Good luck